# Converting a PCAP trace to NetFlow format

Tags: linux, network-programming, pcap, traffic, netflow

I would like to convert some PCAP traces to Netflow format for further analysis with netflow tools. Is there any way to do that?

Specifically, I want to use "flow-export" tool in order to extract some fields of interest from a netflow trace as follows:

```
$ flow-export -f2 -mUNIX_SECS,SYSUPTIME,DPKTS,DOCTETS < mynetflow.trace
```

In this case, the mynetflow.trace file is taken by converting a PCAP file using the following commands:

```
$ nfcapd -p 12345 -l ./ 

$ softflowd -n localhost:12345 -r mytrace.pcap
```

This, generates a netflow trace but it cannot be used by flow-export correctly, since it is not in the right format. I tried also to pipe the output of the following command to flow-export as follows:

```
$ flow-import -V1 -z0 -f0 <mynetflow.trace | flow-export -f2 -mUNIX_SECS,SYSUPTIME,DPKTS,DOCTETS
```

but the output of the first command generated zero timestamps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I took at look at the flow-export documentation and there are some acknowledged bugs with the pcap implementation.  Not sure if they are fixed yet.

Depending on the content of your capture, you have a couple of other options:
If you captured straight-up traffic from a link and you want to turn that into NetFlow format you can download a free netflow exporter tool that reads PCAP here:

[FlowTraq Free Exporter](http://www.flowtraq.com/corporate/product/flow-exporter)

or here:

[NProbe](http://www.ntop.org/products/nprobe/)

If you captured NetFlow traffic in transit (say UDP/2055), then you can replay it with a tool like 'tcpreplay', available in any linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Linux environment, you can use the `argus` Linux package. Just install `argus` using `apt` or your distribution's package manager, and then you can use this with Argus' `ra` client to get the binetflow format.

Here is the command:

```
argus -F /mnt/argus.conf -r " +f+" -w - | ra -F /mnt/ra.conf -Z b -n >"+f.split(".")[0]+".binetflow
```