# tcpdump - how to filter based on tcp connection time / duration

Tags: linux, filtering, tcpdump

Is there a possibility to filter tcpdump (live or after creating a dump) based on tcp connection time (connection duration)?

I'm recording http json rpc traffic. 
I want to record only connections that are longer than lets say 1000 ms.

In wireshark there is tool in Menu->Statistics->Conversations (TCP tab) and there i can sort by "Duration". But i want to record (or filter) long lived connections before (not in wireshark).

In pseudo commands I want to do something like this:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 and connectionTime>1000ms -w data.pcap
```

or after recording:

```
cat data.pcap | SOMETOOL -connectionTime>1000ms > dataLongConnections.pcap
```

SOMETOOL must export filtered data to format that Wireshark will understand.
Because after filtering I want to analyze that data in Wireshark.

How I can do this?

Comment: Did you try SplitCap as suggested by kauppi? You can't filter for session duration with tcpdump, as it's not a stateful filter, SplitCap at first glance seems to provide what you need to get started.

Comment: To add onto what Tom Regner said: `tcpdump` doesn't keep track of session duration. The reason `Wireshark` is able to show you the information is because `Wireshark` itself is keeping track of the session durations, not simply parsing `tcpdump`.

Answer (score 2):

[SplitCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap) might work for you. It will take PCAP as an input and output separate PCAPs for each TCP/UDP session. After the split you could filter from the output PCAPs the interesting ones to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider your traffic at *flow* level instead of *packet* level.

If you worked with [NetFlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow) you could use [flow-tools](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flow-tools) and [flow-nfilter](http://www.splintered.net/sw/flow-tools/docs/flow-nfilter.html) to filter flows by duration. So you could [convert your pcap to NetFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523366/converting-a-pcap-trace-to-netflow-format) and later filter it.

The drawback is that at the output you get NetFlow, not PCAP. For building some stats it is sufficient, but to check packets - not certainly.

You can also build your own tool with [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) in C (hard way) or [scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948043/pcap-python-library) in python (easier way). The latter option shouldn't be too difficult (provided you work with python)