# How to convert pcap file to nfcapd file

Tags: pcap, netflow

I have a pcap file of size 1.4 GB. I am trying to convert this file to nfcapd. But I cannot convert it.

First of all, I typed

```
nfcapd -p 12345 -l ./
```

Then the computer creates some nfcapd file continuously. I tried it 2 days ago and the computer keeps creating nfcapd file until today. Then I stopped the process. Then I tried

```
softflowd -n localhost:12345 -r myFile.pcap
```

Then the terminal gives an error

> Unsupported data link type 104

Do you have any idea to convert this to nfcapd through terminal?

I am using Debian Linux 64 bit OS.

Comment: Maybe you should try some of the commands/tools mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523366/converting-a-pcap-trace-to-netflow-format

Comment: I tried it. But unable to get the solution.

Comment: Might be helpful to provide further information from your part: What did you exactly try? What was the outcome?

Comment: First of all, I typed " nfcapd -p 12345 -l ./" . Then the computer creates some nfcapd file continuously. I tried it 2 days ago and the computer keeps creating nfcapd file till today. Then I stopped the process. Then I tried " softflowd -n localhost:12345 -r myFile.pcap" . Then the terminal gives an error as "Unsupported data link type 104".

Comment: Added information from the comment into the question.

Comment: "Unsupported data link type 104"  What happens if you run the command `file myFile.pcap`?

Comment: If I run file Myfile.pcap, it gives the following output:        Myfile.pcap:tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4 (BSD/OS Cisco HDLC, capture length 48)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could have nfcapd read the pcap file directly** and save it as you specify in your config (Netflow v5 or v9. IPFIX support is currently only experimental).

According to the man page of nfcapd:

> -f <pcap_file>
>
> > Read netflow packets from a give pcap_file instead of the network. This requires nfcapd to be compiled with the pcap option and is intended  for debugging only.

In case you have installed `nfdump` through a packet repository, the chance is high that it is not compiled with the required `--enable-readpcap` flag (which is default off).

Try and download the source from [here](https://github.com/phaag/nfdump) and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, on my x86_64 Fedora 26, I need to use `nfpcapd` (note the extra `p`) to convert a `pcap` file to a netflow file.

```
$ mkdir sipp

$ nfpcapd -l sipp -r /usr/share/sipp/pcap/g711a.pcap
Add extension: 2 byte input/output interface index
Add extension: 4 byte input/output interface index
Add extension: 2 byte src/dst AS number
Add extension: 4 byte src/dst AS number
Add extension: 4 byte output bytes
Add extension: 8 byte output bytes
Add extension: NSEL Common block
Add extension: NSEL xlate ports
Add extension: NSEL xlate IPv4 addr
Add extension: NSEL xlate IPv6 addr
Add extension: NSEL ACL ingress/egress acl ID
Add extension: NSEL username
Add extension: NSEL max username
Add extension: NEL Common block
Startup.
[140499169166528] WaitDone() waiting
pcap_next_ex() end of file
Packet processing stats: Total: 236, Skipped: 0, Unknown: 0, Short snaplen: 0
Packet processing stats: Total: 236, Skipped: 0, Unknown: 0, Short snaplen: 0
Terminating packet dumping: exit: 0
[140499169166528] WaitDone() signal 10
Exit status thread[140498942019328]: 0
[140498950412032] Signal handler: 12
Nodes in use: 1, Flows: 1 CacheOverflow: 0
Ident: 'none' Flows: 1, Packets: 236, Bytes: 61360, Max Flows: 1
Terminating flow processng: exit: 0
Exit status thread[140498950412032]: 0
Terminating nfpcapd.

$ nfdump -v sipp/nfcapd.200207260815 
File    : sipp/nfcapd.200207260815
Version : 1 - not compressed
Blocks  : 1
 Type 1 : 0
 Type 2 : 1
 Type 3 : 0
Records : 2
```